# How to solve empty datasheet result in IIF (SUM IIF) SQL script

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Excel report that I am trying to re-create in MS Access with a SQL query. I have used a IIF SUM function but it is not returning the expected results ("YES") in particular fields, instead just returning blank cells. What is wrong with my script?

I have not used this IIF SUM function before, so I need some help. The SQL query below has been constructed with example table and field names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Table 1].[Paint ID], 
                [Table 1].[Paint Colour], 
                [Table 1].[Production Date], 
                [Table 1].[Price], 
                [Table 1].[VAT], 
                [Table 1].[Total Units],
IIF(Sum(IIF([Table 2].[Company Name] IN("Paintbox Ltd", "ColourSplash plc", "HomeDIY"),1,0))>0,"YES",NULL) AS UK Sellers,
IIF(Sum(IIF([Table 2].[Company Name] IN("BrightWalls", "PerfectHome", "PaintIt"),1,0))>0,"YES",NULL) AS Europe Sellers,
IIF(SUM(IIF([Table 2].[Company Name]="Habari",1,0))>0,"YES",NULL) as Africa Sellers,
IIF(SUM(IIF([Table 2].[Company Name]="Malay Paint",1,0))>0,"YES",NULL) as Asia Sellers
    FROM [Tale 1] LEFT JOIN [Table 2] ON [Table 1].[Paint ID] = [Table 2].[Paint ID]
    GROUP BY [Table 1].[Paint ID], [Table 1].[Paint Colour], [Table 1].[Production Date], [Table 1].[Price], [Table 1].[VAT], [Table 1].[Total Units];
```

I am expecting a grid with columns for UK Sellers, Europe Sellers etc. along the top with 'YES' in some of them as in the excel report. However, they are returning blank. Apart from this, the query is running ok and the result grid is how I expect it to be in its layout, it's just that where I expect 'YES' there are blank cells.

Comment: Can you paste the exact code of your query? Because this code is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your query is correct.
I reproduced it, fixed syntactical errors, added aliases to the tables and removed the `DISTINCT` keyword which is useless since you use `GROUP BY` and this code works as expected:

```
SELECT 
  t1.[Paint ID], 
  t1.[Paint Colour], 
  t1.[Production Date], 
  t1.[Price], 
  t1.[VAT], 
  t1.[Total Units],
IIF(Sum(IIF(t2.[Company Name] IN ("Paintbox Ltd", "ColourSplash plc", "HomeDIY"), 1, 0)) > 0, "YES", NULL) AS UK Sellers,
IIF(Sum(IIF(t2.[Company Name] IN ("BrightWalls", "PerfectHome", "PaintIt"), 1, 0)) > 0,"YES", NULL) AS Europe Sellers,
IIF(SUM(IIF(t2.[Company Name] = "Habari", 1, 0)) > 0, "YES", NULL) as Africa Sellers,
IIF(SUM(IIF(t2.[Company Name] = "Malay Paint", 1, 0)) > 0, "YES", NULL) as Asia Sellers
FROM [Table 1] AS t1 LEFT JOIN [Table 2] AS t2 ON t1.[Paint ID] = t2.[Paint ID]
GROUP BY t1.[Paint ID], t1.[Paint Colour], t1.[Production Date], t1.[Price], t1.[VAT], t1.[Total Units];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `max` aggregate function, so that you can remove one set of `iif` statements entirely, e.g.:

```sql
select
    [Table 1].[Paint ID], 
    [Table 1].[Paint Colour], 
    [Table 1].[Production Date], 
    [Table 1].[Price], 
    [Table 1].[VAT], 
    [Table 1].[Total Units],
    max(iif([Table 2].[Company Name] in ("Paintbox Ltd", "ColourSplash plc", "HomeDIY"),"YES",Null)) as [UK Sellers],
    max(iif([Table 2].[Company Name] in ("BrightWalls", "PerfectHome", "PaintIt"),"YES",Null)) as [Europe Sellers],
    max(iif([Table 2].[Company Name]="Habari","YES",Null)) as [Africa Sellers],
    max(iif([Table 2].[Company Name]="Malay Paint","YES",Null)) as [Asia Sellers]
from 
    [Table 1] left join [Table 2] on [Table 1].[Paint ID] = [Table 2].[Paint ID]
group by 
    [Table 1].[Paint ID], 
    [Table 1].[Paint Colour], 
    [Table 1].[Production Date], 
    [Table 1].[Price], 
    [Table 1].[VAT], 
    [Table 1].[Total Units];
```

Comment: Hi Lee Mac, thank you for your suggestion, I like it. However when I changed my code to this, an error message came up saying that the wrong number of arguments are used in the function in the query expression. Has something been missed?

Comment: @Mari I had forgotten to enclose the aliases `UK Sellers`, `Europe Sellers` etc with square brackets (since such aliases contain spaces). I have now updated the above code - could you please try it?